# Mysql comparison between two datasets

Tags: mysql

I'm having troubles with mysql, I guess I'm missing some special functions to solve my problem.
I have a table, like this:

```
id - user_id - user_property

1  -  45  -  9986
2  -  45  -  9564
3  -  45  -  9225
4  -  45  -  9824
5  -  45  -  9711
6  -  83  -  9711
7  -  83  -  9924
8  -  83  -  9986
9  -  12  -  9933
10 -  12  -  9993
11 -  72  -  9189
12 -  72  -  9711
13 -  72  -  9225
14 -  72  -  9824

user_id+user_property is unique key
```

and I have a list of properties, like "9711","9225","9824". I'm trying to get a list of users having ALL those properties, in the most performant way possible. I've tried many ways, like doing 3 single queries and counting results like this

```
select count(distinct user_id) as tot from 
(     select user_id from mytable where user_property = 9711
union select user_id from mytable where user_property = 9225
union select user_id from mytable where user_property = 9824) as tmp
having tot = 3
```

another guess was to merge user properties per-user and searching wanted properties with the function [FIND_IN_SET](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_find_in_set.asp)(element, set of elements obtained with GROUP_CONCAT(user_properties separator ','))

the problem is, mytable is really huge, I already need to select data from this and another table joined by user_id (and elaborate results another time after) and I'm guessing there is some better way to do that in terms of performances. any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM mytable
    WHERE user_property IN (9711,9225,9824)
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
) users_with_all_properties
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine SUM with IN CLAUSE

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*)
> FROM
> (SELECT 
> user_id,SUM(user_property in (9711, 9225,9824)) sumprop
> FROM mytable 
> GROUP BY user_id
> Having sumprop = 3) userhasprop
> ```
>
> ```
> | COUNT(*) |
> | -------: |
> |        2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e48d501a169ed0416e15bd5dc4ac7e7a)*